# Is this a typo in the Artistic License 2.0?

Tags: licensing, open-source

*I'm not sure if this would fit better in [StackExchange/English](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but regardless, there is no practical use to the answer, other than to cure my curiosity.*

Note this sentence at the end of the [Artistic License 2.0](http://www.perlfoundation.org/attachment/legal/artistic-2_0.txt):

> THE PACKAGE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
>   IS' AND WITHOUT ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES.

It does not affect any legal aspects of the license, but is there a reason they mixed the use of single and double quotes on `"AS IS'`? The license is so new that this wouldn't have been for "command prompt friendly" reasons.

Is there special use or meaning behind this in the English language, or was it a typo?

Comment: ... or alternatively, does the Perl Foundation enjoy torturing obsessive-compulsives?

Comment: That is almost certainly an error - and if you want my speculation, perhaps due to a misfeature in the software used to turn that paragraph into ALL-CAPS. Certainly nobody in their right mind would actually *type* this many shifted characters in a row.

Comment: @KilianFoth I tend to hold shift instead of using the caps lock key!

Comment: It is a typographical error. You should probably report it to the Perl foundation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found the [Artistic License 1.0](http://dev.perl.org/licenses/artistic.html), and looking in the same area, we see that the use of mixed quotes is not present:

> **10.** THIS PACKAGE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND WITHOUT ANY EXPRESS OR
>   IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, WITHOUT LIMITATION, THE IMPLIED
>   WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTIBILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This seems to point towards the fact that the single quote found in the Artistic License 2.0 is indeed a typo.

Comment: In the meantime, would it be permissible to edit this in one's own LICENSE file?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran The license says you may not modify it.